Why is the Clock Signal referred to as SCK instead of CLK in SPI?
I understand "SCK" expands to "Serial Clock", but simply calling it "Clock" would have worked just as fine. Am I right to understand that this "S" is a redundant piece of information?

Context is everything.  If already talking about a SPI bus, then "clock" is sufficient to disambiguate.  But when talking about pins of a processor with 7 UARTs, 4 SPI, 2 I2C, external memory controller, Ethernet, and HDMI... "clock" alone would be very ambiguous.

If you called it just CLK, you risk confusion in the case of, e.g., a microcontroller with an SPI peripheral, which would need a clock output for the SPI communication as well as a clock input (usually; some MCUs are internal-clock-only) to set the MCU's core clock from.
It wouldn't make sense for the SPI peripheral to get to call its pin "CLK" when the core clock is undeniably the more fundamental clock on the chip; what would you then call the clock input pin? (yes, many MCUs use pins named something like XTAL1 and XTAL2 for just attaching a crystal to an on-die Pierce oscillator, but some require a clock input from an external oscillator, and almost all allow an external oscillator. Reserving CLK for an SPI peripheral would still be needlessly confusing in any case.)

Typically a "serial clock" clocks in data one bit at a time, sometimes called "bit clock".
In addition to a serial clock you generally need a framing signal to denote word boundaries and this may be called "word clock" or "frame sync" or in the case of SPI, "chip select".
In addition there may be a high frequency "master clock" that's a multiple of both bit and word clocks.
Calling is "SCLK" instead of merely "CLK" gives a little more information as to what kind of clock it is.

The name serial clock was likely used for clock of bit serial communications that already existed years before someone (Motorola) decided to make a MCU (a few 6805 models in 1983) equipped with a configurable built-in peripheral (called SPI) that simply accelerates the bit serial transfer process in hardware instead of being forced to bit-bang it in software.
That's literally where the name comes from, an interface for serial peripherals.
